# 3 Requests per object with AFIncrementalStore using NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: uitableview, core-data, afnetworking, nsfetchedresultscontroller, afincrementalstore

I have everything setup with AFIncrementalStore to use [Parse](http://parse.com) as a backend service. Using such a service makes counting API requests important as if I exceed 1MM requests/month (though a successful metric!) could result in some decent bills. This usually wouldn't be an issue, but what I'm seeing, if I put a breakpoint at the following method in `AFHTTPClient`:

```objc
- (void)enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:(AFHTTPRequestOperation *)operation;
```

I find that requests for a particular object occurs 3 times, when I only need it once.

```objc
$1 = 0x0b9afe30 https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Poem/cUpTflj0j8
// ...
$8 = 0x099e0a30 https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Poem/cUpTflj0j8
...
$18 = 0x0bb6d530 https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Poem/cUpTflj0j8
```

Note that the different memory addresses come from `AFHTTPRequestOperation`, I'm printing the `request.URL` property to examine the `objectId` (the random string on the end of URL) from each request.

Now I'm not familiar enough with the workings of `NSIncrementalStore` or `AFIncrementalStore` to figure this out after two days of debugging and examination. I'd love to hear any thoughts around what could be causing this, be it intentional or not.

I might add that I'm using a `NSFetchedResultsController` with a `UITableView`. I followed the stack trace of the first request of an object to my tableview's data source. The other 2 requests trace back to methods internal to `AFIncrementalStore`.

```objc
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // ...
    NSManagedObject *poem = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [poem valueForKey:@"title"];  // traced back to here
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An option may be setting up an `NSURLCache` like so:

```
NSURLCache *URLCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:8 * 1024 * 1024 diskCapacity:20 * 1024 * 1024 diskPath:nil];

[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:URLCache];
```

This should set up an `URLCache` using 8 MB RAM and 20 MB disk cache.

To check if there are still this many requests happening on the wire, maybe use a tool like [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [cocoapacketanalyser](http://www.tastycocoabytes.com/cpa/).